# Set export filename in datatable

Tags: jquery, database

Hi everyone I want to set the export file name to my datatable how do i do so using jquery datatable , can someone please help me out with this , thanks

Comment: If you found any solution to set the export filename then please share it.

Comment: the only easiest things i could do is to set the html title of the document again to the required name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just come to know that by default it takes page-title as export file-name. So I hack it and change the tilte of the page using Jquery.

```
$('title').html("Your custom filename");
```

Comment: See solution by @Chandu for a solution that doesn't require you to change the page title. Seems somewhere over the years the function has been build into DataTables itself.

Answer (score 7):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: 'Data export'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                title: 'Data export'
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: As can be seen in the DataTables documentation: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/filename.html

Answer (score 2):

you can set this by sTitle property, check given code

```
tableTools: {
                    "aButtons": [

                     {
                         "sExtends": "pdf",
                         "sTitle": "Customer Fefeedbacks"
                     }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "assets/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                {"sExtends": "xls",
                    "sButtonText": "<span style='color:#fff;'><i class='icon-download-alt icon-white '></i> Excel </span>",
                    "sToolTip": "Save to Excel",
                    "mColumns": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
                    "sFileName":"here you can change the file name !!!",//<-
                    "sTitle": "Title"


                }]

        }
```